# Live search in table PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html-table

I create a simple search engine but I want that whenever I search the name it will display in table as is. The thing is the other data will just hide and I don't know how to do.
This is my Html code.

```
<form name="view" method="post" div class="frm1">
<table align="center" class="record_table" >
<tr bgcolor="#006600" height="50" style="color:#FFF;">
  <th>&nbsp;</th>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Email</th>
  <th>Packages</th>
  <th>Contactno</th>
  <th>Gender</th>
  <th>File</th>
  <th>Address</th>
  <th>Action</th>
</tr>
Search:
<input type="text" size="20" name="search" onKeyup="srch();">
<div id="d1"</>
<script>
function srch()
{
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","dbsearchfile.php?view="+document.view.search.value,false);
xmlhttp.send(null);
document.getElementById("d1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
</script>
```

And this is my PHP code.

```
<?php
$view=$_GET['view'];
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("pm");
$res=mysql_query("select * from tblreservation where Name like ('$view%');");
echo "<table>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<div class=frm1>";
echo "<a href='#'>". $row['Name'] . "</a>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Your HTML has syntax errors (`<div id="d1"</>`), your php code has syntax errors, you are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, your ajax code is incorrect and does not WAIT for a response to come in from the server, etc...

Comment: What do you mean by "display in table as is"?  Are you saying you want to filter the original table data based on some search without reloading the page?

Comment: live search through table rows using by name.

Comment: You miss closing `"` in `mysql_select_db("pm);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See:

```
<div id="d1"</>
```

Correct:

```
<div id="d1"></div>
```

AND

```
$res=mysql_query("select * from tblreservation where Name like ('$view%');");
```

Suggestion:

```
$res=mysql_query(" select * from tblreservation where Name like '".$view."%'; ");
```

Comment: Live search table php and mysql

Answer (score 0):

I think it's too complicated to do it on PHP side. I would suggest to use jQuery.FilterTable plugin to stay on client-side and do your filtering there. You will get a live-search without page-reload. But a refetch is possible with Ajax.

Plugin: http://sunnywalker.github.io/jQuery.FilterTable/

Demo: http://sunnywalker.github.io/jQuery.FilterTable/filtertable-sample.html